# Get a tooltip by mouseover with Fusion Tables

Tags: html, tooltip, mouseover, google-fusion-tables

As a beginning self-made amateur programmer I’m currently trying to get some things done with Google Fusion Tables.

I made a map with markers and got the HTML of that map. But I wish to add the function of a tooltip by a mouseover of a particular marker. I found a [tutorial](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/examples.html) to work this out but I can’t enable the tooltips.

The following link shows the progress so far: http://jsbin.com/cipejicewo/1/watch?html,js,output

1 I don’t have to change something in this script that fits to the specific Fusion Table where its linked with, do I? When I do have to change the javascript, what are the specific elements I have to rename?

2 How can i call google.maps.FusionTablesLayer.enableMapTips(options)? And where do I have to put this whole ‘function init’ code in the html-file? Directly in the script that described above?  Off course without losing the functions that the html already provides. Besides that, I get that I have to change the tableid and change the select column and geometry column name, but is there something more I should change in this function I'm going to add?

I'm struggeling with it now for days. And I'm out of options, so every help would be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your code currently looks like, but these 2 things you'll need to do first:

1. when you use another FusionTable than the example, make sure that the table is public and downloadable
2. You must use your own key(it's the variable `apiConsoleKey` in the example). Follow the steps in [**Acquiring and using an API key**](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#APIKey) to get a valid key.

Comment: The code can be found at the jsbin-link 1. The FusionTable is now public and downloadable 2. I used my own API key in the jsbin-link in the re-edited question.

Comment: 1. you didn't set the `key`-property of the `enableMapTips`-options. 2. you must enable the Fusion Tables API for  the project where the used key applies to(currently the API doesn't seem to be  enabled). Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/3b94r77r/ (Note: the used key is only valid for my own jsfiddle-account. When you update or fork the example you must use your own key)

Comment: It's working. Many thanks! But one problem evolves; I customized the info window in Fusion Tables, but after adding the tooltips the customized style of the info window has been deleted. Should I also customize the content of the Info Window in java script?